# Solution for sending data from server to clients (web, mobile devices) in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there solution in AWS for sending filtered data from server to clients (web, mobile devices) or for specific client by subscription?

Comment: What is "filtered" data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has the Simple Notification Service that has subscription and publish functionality. For example, you can code a web app that lets you publish a message and then the message is sent via email (there are other channels too) to all subscribed clients.

Here is an example app that shows this functionality and built with the ***AWS SDK for Java***.

[Creating a Publish/Subscription Spring Boot Application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_sns_sample_app)

(This type of solution can be built with other programming languages too that are supported by the AWS SDK. This Java example is just one way to invoke AWS SNS functionality).

Comment: Could user subscribe to specific messages, for example messages contains field country with value: "USA" and value "FR"? And how to push these messages to clients (web, mobile applications)?

Comment: Good question. Clients subscribe to the SNS topic (vs message content like "USA") and receive published messages. More information here- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: Thank you, I wonder about how message is sent to web application writtern on JS or mobile app?

Comment: Lets assume I get message in SNS then I want to broadcast this message to all clients (JS web pages) who is subscribed.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-system-to-system-messaging.html

Comment: Thank you, so sending data from SNS to endpoint I can resend message to client using socket?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a job for AWS SNS (https://aws.amazon.com/en/sns)